# SQL IF to Set Parameter Value Within SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

EDIT: This problem has been solved using a better method. Rather than using a variable I am concatenating results to get my desired output.

I am trying to get values from several fields from a couple of different tables and that works fine. But I would also like to have a "@Description" which is a concatenation of hard coded text based on existing values for each row.

```
DECLARE @Description VARCHAR(1000) = ''

SELECT t1.ID
      t1.myType
      t1.myName
      ,CASE WHEN 
      (
          t1.aValue1 = 1 
          AND t1.aValue2 = 1
          AND t2.aValue1 = 1
          AND t2.aValue2 = 1
      )
         THEN 'ELIGIBLE'
         ELSE 'NOT ELIGIBLE'
       END AS 'isEligible'

      ,@Description 
      -- Then I'm trying to set the description 
      /*
      IF    
          (
            t1.aValue1 = 2
          )
      SET @Description = @Description + ' t1.aValue1 is 2'
      IF
          (
            t1.aValue2 = 2
          )
      SET @Description = @Description + ' t1.aValue2 is 2'    
      IF
          (
            t2.aValue1 = 2
          )
      SET @Description = @Description + ' t2.aValue1 is 2'    
      IF
          (
            t2.aValue2 = 2
          )
      SET @Description = @Description + ' t2.aValue2 is 2'        
      */
      END AS 'Description'

  FROM [dbo].[Table1] t1
  JOIN [dbo].[Table2] t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

So for example, if a row had a t1.aValue1 = 2 and t2.aValue1 = 2 then the output might look something like this.

```
ID | myType | myName | isEligible | Description
-----------------------------------------------
... 
24 | Red | John | Not Eligible | t1.aValue1 is 2 t2.aValue1 is 2
25 | Blue | Eric | Eligible | 
etc...
```

I am using SSMS 2008 R2.
How would I accomplish this?

Comment: You can't mix data retrieval and variable assignments in one `SELECT`.

Comment: My guess is you don't need the variable here. You probably just need to use a case expression. However, from what you posted it is hard to tell for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the variable, but the expected results looks like you actually want it to the row? You can get it to the row just by using case, something like this:

```
 END AS isEligible,
 case when t1.aValue1 = 2 then 't1.aValue1 is 2 ' else '' end +
 case when t1.aValue2 = 2 then 't1.aValue2 is 2 ' else '' end +
 case when t2.aValue1 = 2 then 't2.aValue1 is 2 ' else '' end +
 case when t2.aValue2 = 2 then 't2.aValue2 is 2 ' else '' end as Description
```